# Is electric field by a charge present where the net field is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory

I have heard a lot of people say that, at all the points where electric field is zero, electric field by any of the charges never reaches there. It's quite commonly thrown around that electric field knows that it is going to be zero at those points and therefore never goes at those points. For e.g. in the Young's double slit experiment, the points of minima are witnessed when intensity is zero. This means that there is no field present there. Now if my doubt statement is not true, then some field by both the slits must have gone there and thus there must have been some net zero field because the fields would be out of phase, but still if the field went there, then some energy has reached that point... Which is not true... Thus field must have never gone at that point by either of the slits. Is all of this true?

Comment: *"It's quite commonly thrown around that electric field knows that it is going to be zero at those points and therefore never goes at those points."* - I've never once heard that 'thrown around'.

Comment: Kirk T. McDonald has a series of great (and rigorous) examples of physics problems at: [http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/](http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/).  Look up the example entitled, `Does Destructive Interference Destroy Energy?`.  He has several others relating to your question and none of them just _throw around_ the arguments.

Comment: I did not just write thrown around... It actually is thrown around a lot amongst my peers, and I'm the only one who never agrees... Sorry if it seemed a little unpleasant...